# Project Based learning

Tags: python-3.x

I have been learning python for about 1 month and half now.But i heard watching tutorials dont help if you dont practice.i practice the code that is shown in the video and then see how it works.But the more i am learning the more i am forgetting.So i want to dive into "Project Based Learning".Any tips and guides how to do that?PLease dont tell me make something that interests you.There are lot of things i actually have in my mind but how do i start? :(  pretty confused for a while.It was fun learning but i am going nowhere now :"( .As an example lets assume that i want to make a weather desktop app with tkinter.But i dont know what to start with :( .Do i search "How to make weather app ?".Then it gives me the whole code.Do i look into it and understand and make my version of it?But i heard  there peoples who are making from scratch.how is that possible.i have a whole year totally free.I want to get a job as a software developer/Python developer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, this website is more for programming related issues rather than open ended questions or non-programming related suggestions. For such advice, you can look at some other stackexchange site or some other place like r/learnpython on reddit. Also, do look at the guidelines provided for asking questions

Comment: Thank You.i thougth i would get an answer here .I will post somewhere else then